# C++ mapping a type to its header file

Tags: c++, types, header, xtext

I am currently developing a simple programming language for easily creating C++ projects. It lets you type in some short C++-like code and generates .h and .cpp files automatically.

I need some way to **map a type**, e.g. from the standard library, **to its corresponding header file**. That makes it possible to just use a type in my language and automatically infer which headers to include in the generated code.

Here is an example of the language as it is right now:

```c
class Car {
    std::string print()

    members:
        int i, j
        std::array<Wheel, 4> wheels
}
```

When processing this code I find the types `std::string` and `std::array` which need to be mapped to their header files. **How can I achieve this mapping?**

Is there maybe a data base publicly available? I do not want to parse all the headers myself of course (which I assume is how IDEs do it).

On top of only supporting the standard library it would of course be useful to be able to support other libraries as well, but that is only a secondary goal.

Comment: For the standard library, you can simply hard-code it. For arbitrary headers, you can employ a C++ parser (like Clang's front end) to parse the headers. If you're developing a project as ambitious as you say, using a 3rd-party C++ parser shouldn't be problematic.

Comment: What do you mean by hard-coding it? The STL comprises thousands of types, how should I do that (instead of by hand)?
I like your second proposal! Have you ever done something like that and can point me to something to help me with using the Clang parser in my project?

Comment: Create some sort of mapping file or something like that. It will only require updating once every 3 or so years, when the standard changes. Or you can use a parser for the standard headers as well, of course.

Comment: Nope, sorry; I've read the LLVM tutorials, but I haven't actually used Clang yet. I just know it has a parser API, even a Python binding for it.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are some excellent references that you can use to build your own database. As the standards are slow-changing you can generate a map for them by using the references. Here is a good [c++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header)

It's hard to simply go around searching in the header files as they are typically built up using back-end bits that you do not want to use in your code and you can't distinguish between them.

If I were to build this I'd build the basic map using a standard library reference rather than parsing through header files; For example in the Car example above you  should `#include <string>` right?

If you were to parse the header file `<string>` for a given  compiler  you may find that it is only made up of back-end bits that in-turn include other files;

In g++ version 4.6 `<string>` looks like this:

```
// Copyright (C) 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004,
// 2005, 2006, 2007, 2009, 2010, 2011
// Free Software Foundation, Inc.
// GPL version 3.1 or later ... etc...

#ifndef _GLIBCXX_STRING
#define _GLIBCXX_STRING 1

#pragma GCC system_header

#include <bits/c++config.h>
#include <bits/stringfwd.h>
#include <bits/char_traits.h>  // NB: In turn includes stl_algobase.h
#include <bits/allocator.h>
#include <bits/cpp_type_traits.h>
#include <bits/localefwd.h>    // For operators >>, <<, and getline.
#include <bits/ostream_insert.h>
#include <bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h>
#include <bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h>
#include <bits/stl_iterator.h>
#include <bits/stl_function.h> // For less
#include <ext/numeric_traits.h> 
#include <bits/stl_algobase.h> 
#include <bits/range_access.h>
#include <bits/basic_string.h>
#include <bits/basic_string.tcc> 

#endif /* _GLIBCXX_STRING */
```

The problem now becomes evident. For example is `<string>` canonical for `std::ios_base` ? 
Lots to think about,  I may have some other thoughts on it later.

Comment: That is a very good idea, your point is very important. The next question that arises is: How would you go about building the map from a website? I am not a web developer and have no idea how to transform the information and put it in my own data base?

Comment: @user1286875 well if you are skilled enough to write a parser, then  that's not a difficult question to answer; download the ref from a source and parse it using perl; or if you are a beginner; I would suggest starting with a subset of the language, create the database manually, there are only 100 or so base objects, and then building it as you go along;

Comment: Thank you again for your answer, I managed to create the database after `wget`ing the refrence, looking at the html files and writing a little python function to go through the file tree and extract all types and their corresponding headers.